# Get parent of custom taxonomy in Yoast variable snippet

Tags: wordpress, function, parent-child, taxonomy, yoast

I have a directory wordpress website that is using a custom taxonomy. The hierarchy is setup as follows: country > state > city. When I put the custom taxonomy into Yoast for the SEO title and meta description it's pulling in the city only. I'm looking to pull in the state also by creating a new Yoast variable snippet that will grab the parent(being the state) of current URL the user is on.

This is what I have so far in my functions.php file, but it's bringing in the country. So it's currently bringing in the top level parent. How can I get immediate parent, which would be the state?

```
function get_state() {
$myterms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'w2dc-location', 'parent' => 0 ) );
  foreach($myterms as $term) {
    return $term->name;
  }
}

function register_custom_yoast_variables() {
   wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%state%%', 'get_state', 'advanced', 'some help text' );
}

add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_custom_yoast_variables');
```

website link: https://www.helpingmehear.com/find-an-expert/hearing-aids/united-states/colorado/castle-rock/accent-on-hearing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that will return City and State, given that you've only chosen one taxonomy (city) and that state is the direct parent of city.  I think that instead of `get_terms()` you want to use `get_the_terms()`

```
function get_state() {
    global $post;
    // Get the terms for the current post in your tax
    $myterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'w2dc-location' );
    // Check if parent exists
    if ($myterms[0]->parent !== 0){
        // Get the term object
        $parent = get_term_by('id', $myterms[0]->parent, 'w2dc-location');
        return $parent->name;
    }
}

function register_custom_yoast_variables() {
   wpseo_register_var_replacement( 'state', 'get_state', 'advanced', 'some help text' );
}
add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_custom_yoast_variables');
```

Usage in Yoast Title box...

`%%category%% %%state%%`

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `custom post taxonomy` you can use this code to get the `parent category` very easily for `wpseo_register_var_replacement` custom function:

```
// Return custom post taxonomy name by ID
function get_game_cat() {
    return get_the_term_list(get_the_ID(), 'game_category');
}
function register_custom_yoast_variables() {
 wpseo_register_var_replacement('game_cat', 'get_game_cat', 'advanced', 'Current Game Category');
}
add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_custom_yoast_variables');
```

Usage in Yoast SEO boxes as `custom_variable`:

```
%%game_cat%%
```